# Can you share a VPN from one device to other devices on a local network?

Tags: networking, vpn

I have a laptop with a Cisco AnyConnect VPN, I would like other devices on my local network to resolve certain domains using this VPN is this possible?

Comment: If you use a Hardware VPN in a VPN router, yes you can access all devices inside the router network.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No

Long answer: Possibly

If you are on linux you could setup the machine connected to the vpn to [NAT connections](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Masquerading-Simple-HOWTO/) from the other machines onto the VPN. You'll have to work out the routing table on the clients yourself, based on what routes the VPN sets up.

Under Windows this can be more difficult as the built in network sharing expects you to have a second wired/wireless interface to share over. This will cause ALL traffic on the other machines to go via the Windows machine connected to the VPN.

[This guide](https://www.vpnmentor.com/blog/share-vpn-windows/) seems to be accurate on how to set it up.

The other way would be to configure the VPN on your router. This is very dependent on what router you have and I can't really provide generic advice